# Phone connecting as mass-storage: how can I import photos?

Tags: 12.04, android, photo-management

When I connect my Android phone to Ubuntu computed via USB, no photos can be imported. The new USB drive is opened instead containing my various junk from SD-CARD which is a phone's optional external storage. The partition holding photos & videos is unaccessible.

Comment: What phone? what rom, how do you connect to it, add a screenshot how does it look when you're connected do you have them in the phone memory or on asdcard? important things you shouldn't left out, mine works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to go under **System Settings** and select **Removable Media** ?  Also, on the Android-based phones, you have to select whether or not the phone makes itself visible as USB drive.

Comment: No, I cannot get photos partition available via USB. Windows sees a phone also as camera, Ubuntu doesn't.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add more info, such as your phone type and a more detailed description of what is happening?